# Find break points in a curve

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a set of [data](https://www.mediafire.com/file/cqo5h6v710b1ctq/test_break_curve.csv/file) (less than 6kB) that has a breaking point when plotted (for example, using `ListPlot`).

```
testbreak = ToExpression /@ Import["~\\test_break_curve.csv"];
plt = ListPlot[testbreak, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, All}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I want to find the coordinates of the breaking point(s) so that I can plot it with `ListLinePlot` as two segments of continuous curves (in solid lines) instead of points.
In other words, I don't want the part in the black box but need the coordinates of the two points in the circles. The following figure is plotted with `ListLinePlot`. Is there a method to do this? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choice of transition step as `0.1` is arbitrary.

```
blist = testbreak[[All, 2]] // Differences;
pos = Position[blist, _?(Abs@# > 0.1 &)]
```

> {{122}}

Coordinates for the transition

```
excl = testbreak[[{122, 123}]]
```

> {{2.425, -0.584512}, {2.445, -1.09194}}

```
TakeDrop[testbreak, Det@pos] //
 ListLinePlot[#
   , PlotStyle -> Thick
   , Epilog -> {Dashed, Red, Line@excl}
   ] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We split the points of sequence by the `Max` difference quotient.

```
index=Ordering[
 Abs[(Last[#2] - Last[#1])/(First[#2] - First[#1])] & @@@ 
  Partition[testbreak, 2, 1], -1]//First
```

> `122`

```
pts = TakeList[testbreak, {index - 1, 2, All}];
pts[[2]]
ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed, Green}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html):

```
ListLinePlot[
 Split[
  testbreak,
  Abs[#[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < 0.1 &
  ]
 ]
```

[image]